# Ripping sound from avi video file to mp3? (on Windows)

Tags: video, audio, mp3, avi, ripping

Ripping sound from `.avi` video file to `.mp3`? (on Windows)

What software (free) can do the task ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used Avidemux and find it intuitive. It's free, cross platform.

http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/

Answer (score 1):

[MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/) should work. And, yes, it is [free and works on Windows](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/download.htm).

It clearly lists this as one of its applications,

> Extracting audio track from video files

If you AVI happens to have some other audio, it will also convert it to MP3 for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [This Audio Converter](http://www.riverpast.com/en/prod/audioconverter/) with success in the past. here's a tutorial [AVI to MP3](http://www.riverpast.com/en/support/tutorials/convert/avi/mp3.php)

Main page is here:

http://www.riverpast.com/en/support/tutorials/convert/avi/index.php

Not free, unfortunately, but very powerful. An alternative, free solution can be found here: [How to convert the audio in a video to WAV (or MP3)](http://www.videohelp.com/guides/how-to-convert-the-audio-in-a-video-to-wav-or-mp3-id101#101)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using command line, have a try at **ffmpeg** with *libmp3lame enabled*. The command should be:

```
ffmpeg -i inputvideo.avi -vn -acodec mp3 outputaudio.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free version of Goldwave, version 4 (probably 4.26 something)
"We don't need no stinking tutorials ..." ;)  Because it's just loading the avi, and saving as MP3. By default, it's set at 128kbps, but you can change that.

It's exactly like saving a doc file as text.